# Issues deleting or adding rows from .txt, using grep or sed

Tags: sed, grep

I’m trying to edit a large number of `.txt` files using R on a windows machine. I got stuck trying to save all rows that begin with a  `>` character to a new `.txt` file. 
I have tried a bunch of solutions suggested in other threads like:

```
grep -v "^>"  filename

sed  -i "/^</ d"  filename
```

But I keep getting the standard error:

> unexpected string constant

I’m relatively new to R in general and to string manipulation in particular.  Any ideas on where I should start looking, do I need escapes for the `>` sign, do I need to format the `.txt`s, or am I just messing up some basic syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running `grep -v "^>"  filename` in your R session or in your terminal? Sounds like in your session, hence the error. The R function grep() works differently from the Unix `grep` command, and `sed` is not available at all.

You might try opening another terminal (or exit out of your R session) and try those commands at a BASH prompt.

In order to do text manipulation with `R`, you first have to use something like readLines() to get the file into an R object, then you can use `R`'s text functions like `grep()`, then writeLines() to save the changes you made to the file.

Something like:

```
z <- readLines("file.txt")
y <- z[grep("^>", z, invert=TRUE)]
writeLines(y, "file.txt")
```

should work.

Comment: That might well be the issue. Do you have any suggestions on how I could do this within R. This is only the first step of a longer process so I really want to avoid any non automated steps